# Can we separate commands in LFS?

Tags: configure, lfs

I am trying to build a Linux by using Linux from scratch tutorial ,but i can't explain this,when i run multiple command as [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/binutils-pass2.html) step describe:

```
CC=$LFS_TGT-gcc                \
AR=$LFS_TGT-ar                 \
RANLIB=$LFS_TGT-ranlib         \
../binutils-2.24/configure     \
    --prefix=/tools            \
    --disable-nls              \
    --with-lib-path=/tools/lib \
    --with-sysroot
```

I get errors like :

```
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
```

But when i separate this part:

```
CC=$LFS_TGT-gcc                \
AR=$LFS_TGT-ar                 \
RANLIB=$LFS_TGT-ranlib         \
```

from this part:

```
../binutils-2.24/configure     \
    --prefix=/tools            \
    --disable-nls              \
    --with-lib-path=/tools/lib \
    --with-sysroot
```

And run them in two sequential sequence,it goes good,without error.as i know first part define some system variable and second part configure the program,but i don't realize why the combination give me an error? and is it okey to run them separately?

Comment: What does `file $LFS_TGT-gcc $LFS_TGT-ar $LFS_TGT-ranlib` output? The **cannot run C compiled programs** error indicates that they're not recognized as executables on your current OS. Are you running on a filesystem that is `nosuid` or encrypted?

Comment: apparently those files don't exist,i don't know when they suppose to create!i do exact steps.

Comment: OK, you can go back and repeat older steps. To answer part of your question: when you have `variable=value` on the **beginning of the same line** as a command, it temporarily puts that variable in the command's environment. So `CC=this AS=that configure` will temporarily make `configure` use those values for CC and AS instead of the ones it uses by default. This is important if you're compiling software for a different target architecture than the one you're on.

Answer (score 0):

From Page [xviiii in the typography section](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/downloads/stable-systemd/LFS-BOOK-7.5-systemd.pdf):

> In some cases, a logical line is extended to two or more physical
>   lines with a backslash at the end of the line.
>
> Note that the backslash must be followed by an immediate return. Other
>   whitespace characters like spaces or tab characters will create
>   incorrect results.

Please note that these commands could be *one-liners* but contain the backslash to increase readability.